# Is it possible to "cover up" a FM signal with your one?

Tags: interference, frequency-modulation

So my question is, if there is a way to use a FM transmitter and send a signal on the same frequency as the local Radio, so that radios only play my signal. Or will it just be interference.  In other words: Are FM recivers able to choose a stronger signal over a weaker one, or will they display both?
Thanks in advance.
PS: I know that Personal use would be Illegal.

Comment: We should probably make a note here of the **HIGHLY ILLEGAL** nature of actually attempting to do this!

Comment: Good luck dealing with the cops.

Comment: Its actually not illegal if you have a small signal, personal FM radio transmitters do this all the time, but the range is usually under 100ft. If you turn up the power, there is a good chance you'll get a talking to by the FCC

Comment: well if the FCC wants to swing by Germany thats cool by me, But i do get your point :)

Comment: @user6003203 Don't worry, you certainly have a Bundes-CC of some sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FM receivers have a "capture effect" with the stronger signal overriding the weaker signal.

Comment: Awesome, is there a general threshold, or is it reciver to reciver kind of thing?

Comment: It's based on signal strength at the location of the receiver. Also, this is, as mentioned above, __very illegal__.

Comment: It only needs a few dBs difference in received signal strength. This means that if the level is just enough for the radios in your house to capture your signal, the rest of the area will capture the broadcast signal in preference to yours.

Comment: Thank you.
The Illegal part is fine, I´m not into making my own Radio. I though it might be a practical tool for emergency personnel to inform people in certain situations.

Comment: @user6003203 - bcos ofc you can [broadcast on all frequencies](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DoNotAdjustYourSet) all at the same time ... not ... ;)

Comment: ok stupid question but what does "bcos ofc" mean. Sorry i´m German.
And yes i know :)

Comment: @user6003203 "bcos ofc" = "because of course"

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned FM receivers lock-in to the strongest signal in the vicinity, within limits. This is different from AM where one channel will just mix with the other.

This is one of the reasons FM if much more prevalent than AM. You can pack way more stations into a given bandwidth and the stations with the same wavelength can be a geographically a lot closer together.

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, if there are two competing FM carriers, then the one that will theoretically "win" has to be at least 6 dB greater in amplitude at the receiver antenna than the other. This is because an FM receiver gets rid of amplitude noise by hard-limiting the received carrier and, an interfering signal can be regarded as amplitude noise because it isn't coherent with the larger signal.

With one signal at 6 dB greater amplitude than the other, the resulting limited composite signal will contain only the modulated carrier of the larger signal. Consider two similar amplitude FM carriers and the composite wave they produce when added: -

[image]

Clearly there is destructive interference at the "difference" frequency and this cannot be got rid of by a limiter because the signal disappears. However, as the amplitude of one of those signals rises there becomes a point when a limiter can work: -

[image]

This is simplistic and theoretical. In practise, a few dB more is usually necessary for decent FM listener quality.

Comment: Commercial FM tuners generally cite capture rations of a couple of dB.

Comment: How about some maths on why only couple dB suffice? Are several cascaded limiters required? What about bandwidths?

Comment: Feel free to make a more mathematically oriented answer.

Comment: It actually depends on the effectiveness of the limiting amplifier in the RX. Better limiters require less difference for capture.